# Ruby: Check for connectivity

Tags: ruby, shell, command-line

How do I check if network connectivity is present in Ruby?

So far I have tried stuff like

```
`ping -c 1 8.8.8.8`
unless $?
  abort("There was an error")
end
```

But I would be amazed if there was not some easily available and better way to perform a mundane task such as this.

Comment: Both answers upped now!

Comment: No offence but why? I haven't even seen those questions before

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to attempt to open a socket, and if it fails, then you're not connected. This is an expensive operation compared to checking a status bit in a more operating-system-specific way, but it's simple and effective.

```
require 'open-uri'

def connected?
  open("http://example.com/") rescue false
end
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this operation might be heavier than what I was looking for. I was aiming for something akin to sending just a few packages (like a ping, but manually running a system command feels kinda dumb)

Comment: Starting up a shell that spawns a process that opens a socket is definitely more expensive than just opening the socket, so this should at least be a little faster than the `ping` approach.

Comment: Does every system call in ruby spawn a new shell? If so, I gotta rework my Ruby mentality.

Comment: Every command within backticks spawns a shell. Ruby does not interpret sh/bash by itself.